# how to control the password fild with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a form for a website with javascript, and I am trying to control the password field. I am using this jscript function

```
 function passcheck() {
    var pass=document.getElementById('password');
    if (pass.value.length<=6)
    {alert("The password must me greater the");


    }

   }
```

and the form":

```
<input type="password" name="password1"  onchange="passcheck()">
```

but it doesnt function.
what can I do? please help me

I solve it. NOw my function lokk like this

```
   function passcheck() {
    var pass=document.getElementById('password1');
      if (pass.value.length<=6)
    {alert("The password must me greater the"); 

    }
      }
```

But I would like to show the message not in a alert but I would like to show it  at the right af the input..How can I do thi

Now I want to dissable the button when the password is less then 6 characters. I have done this function

```
function passcheck() {
    var pass=document.getElementById('password1');
    var sb=document.getElementById('submit');
      if (pass.value.length<=6)
    {document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block';
    sb.disable=true;}
     else
      {
        sb.disable=false;
       }
```

and the html part is this

```
 <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1"  class="textinput" onchange="passcheck()"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="location.href='userlogin.html'" class="button" ><br>
```

but the button is still enablet... What can I do?

```
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have an ID on that element, a better way would be to pass in `this` in your inline handler, and add a param to your function:

```
<input type="password" name="password1"  onchange="passcheck(this)">

function passcheck(elem) {
    var pass = elem.value;
    if (pass.value.length<=6)
    {
        alert("The password must me greater the");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank I solve it. BUt vcan you help me for another thing I just mentionet above

Comment: Create a `span` that is hidden on page load, if theres an error, show the span.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you but can you help me again if it it possibele for the problem I posted now?

Comment: You have a typo, its `disabled` not `disable` :)

Comment: But now also when I type more then 6 characters the button is still dissabled and the error msg appeared again.. i=even that i have defined this at the else part...do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yoy should use, OnBlur, since it activates when the cursor leaves the textbox